# 500 (Internal Server Error) , post request

Tags: ajax, laravel, request

the wierd thing that this works when i use it in routes.php

[script file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0dKw.jpg)

[Controller method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWYHE.jpg)

any one knows whats happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding "\" before the Illuminate

```
public function addItem(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
```

Comment: try this in your "if" ` if(\Illuminate\Http\Request::ajax())` coz it might because of the class not found

Comment: in L5 App\Http\Requests doesnt exists.   App\Http\Requests is too broad, you need to specify the class you need.

use 'use Request;' or try removing your "if" if its works